# ImagePicker in a popover does not hide

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have read that the iPad must use a `UIPopoverController` to view the PhotoLibrary, however, I have edited the code to make it, the popover shows but it does not hide when I choose a picture.

I found that it does not reach the `didFinishpickingMediaWithInfo`. Am I missing anything? here is my code

```
-(IBAction) ButtonClicked{

    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    ipc.delegate=self;
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ipc];
    [ipc release];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 400.0) 
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                           animated:YES];   
}
```

here:

```
-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

and here:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishpickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

 // TempImage is a UIImage instance
    TempImg = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    //bgImage is a UIImageView instance and it's connected in the IB
    [bgImage setImage:TempImg];
    // Dismiss UIImagePickerController and release it
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker release];
}
```

I really need someone's help, I have already watched every youtube video, read every article on the internet and tried almost everything. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What happens if you comment out `[ipc release]`?

Comment: Is `-imagePickerDidCancel:` getting fired?

Comment: No.
If you do not mind, I want to ask you a question to not to waste your time, what i know is, the didFinishPicking should work when I click a photo from the photo library, right?
Or should I provide a button or something ?

Answer (score 7):

The first problem is that the method `didFinishpickingMediaWithInfo` is spelled wrong and so it won't get called.  It should be `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` (uppercase P for Picking).

Second problem is calling dismiss on the parent or the picker will not hide the popover.  Instead, try calling `[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`.